# How to use datas one by one from fetching with find('all',) in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to match `course_id` with `$courseInfo` which is fetching from `$cLID`.

When I change this `$clID['Relationscl']['course_id']` line as `1` everything is ok, but the other way an error appears like **Undefined index: Relationscl**.

Here is my code:

```
$this->loadModel('Course');
$this->loadModel('Lecturer');


$clID = $this->Relationscl->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array(
                'student_id' => $id

        ),
        'fields' => array(
                'course_id','lecturer_id'
        )
));



$this->set('clIDs', $clID);

$courseInfo = $this->Course->find('first',array(
        'conditions' => array(
                'course_id' => $clID['Relationscl']['course_id']
        ),
        'fields' => array(
                'course_name','course_code','course_credit'
        )
));


$this->set('cInfos', $courseInfo);
```

Comment: What does `var_dump($clID)` shows?

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but the `find('all')`  function returns and indexed array, so it should be something like

```
$clID = array( 0 => array('Relationscl'=>array('course_id'=>1 /*and more fields*/)),
               1 => array('Relationscl'=>array('course_id'=>2 /*and more fields*/))
        /*etc*/);
```

So clearly `$clID['Relationscl']` is undefined. Try with `$clID[0]['Relationscl']`. Though even that seems weird, why would you do a `find('all')` if you only plan on using the *one* record, isn't `find('first')` better? Or set that `$courseInfo` definition inside a loop?

Comment: Actually, I try to find courses and lectures taken by students. Im beginner on coding CakePHP. Firstly, I get student_id from the URL ("ex. relationscls/courseLecturer/1"). As you see student_id is "1", then a try to find course's id and lecturer's id from the database by using $clID definition and I should use loop for that to catch all courses and lecturers. On  the $courseInfo definition I tried to match course's id by which is came from $clID definition. I guess "$clID['Relationscl']['course_id']" is undefined as u said. How can i define it?

Comment: You don't need to define the index, you need to adjust the reference so you're accessing the right guy for the job. The find('all') comes as an indexed array, so there's no `$clID['Relationscl']`, but there is (unless there's no records in the db) a `$clID[0]['Relationscl']` (notice the index, please). If you do this in a loop, clearly that zero is going to change to go through all Relationscl found, but for now, just add the zero as the first index and see if that works to eliminate the undefined notice. And in the future, do a debug of the variable with the problem to check its structure.

Comment: I did $clID[0]['Relationscl'] but only appeared [0] index on the screen. Imagine that, I have relationscls table in my database. It keeps course_id student_id and lecturer_id. When I click on the name of the student, I would like to see the courses taken by him or her. I have courses, students and lecturers tables too. I'm trying to match student_id in $clID definition with a loop. But i can not fetch it in cakePhP.

Comment: Again, did you do a debug of the $cIID variable?

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/836/duz.png/    --- This is the link of screenshot. Im beginner about cakephp.

Comment: Also, I do not know debug any variable.

Comment: Then you need to start reading [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php)

Comment: I guess this is the debug.    -------
array (size=2)
0 => 
array (size=1)
'Relationscl' =>
array (size=2)
          'course_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'lecturer_id' => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'Relationscl' => 
        array (size=2)
          'course_id' => string '2' (length=1)
          'lecturer_id' => string '2' (length=1)

Comment: Nunser, can you help me about this problem. I can tell everythin that I need. Its easy I guess but there are some rules in cakePhp and I do not know them. I hope you can help me, I have to fix thiss problem next 3 hours.